# python multiprocess hangs at .join only when using logical processor count

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a fairly simple program that I am trying to run in parallel. The program works when I run it using 4 processes. The processor I have is a 4 core processor with 8 logical cores. When I increase the number of processes from 4 to 5+, the program will run with the increased number of processes up until it hits .join() where the program hangs...whereas if I keep it at 4 or less, it never hangs and finishes properly. Are there different considerations that need to be made when spawning more processes than physical cores in your machine that I haven't thought of? Here's some example code of what I'm doing to create and run the processes.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(list1, list2):
    #do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = list()
    list2 = list()
    procs = list()

    num_cores = 4

    for i in xrange(0, num_cores):
        p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(list1, list2,))
        procs.append(p)

    for p in procs:
        p.start()

    for p in procs:
        p.join() # hangs here with num_cores over 4
```

Comment: In general, you can spin up many more processes that cores. It all depends on what `f` does. For instance, I made `f` simply return without doing anything and upped `num_cores` to 400 on my linux system and it took about 2 seconds to run.

Comment: Windows is very different than linux. multiprocessing will pickle parts of the current enviroment, run a new python, unpickle and then run the function. That is often slower and may burn through system resources more quickly, but shouldn't hang up for more modest subprocess counts.

Comment: In my actual program, I pass it a few lists, f then creates all string permutations of the items on the lists and adds them to an mp.Queue that f returns at the end. There is some logic so I only save about 20 items per process to its Queue but that's really it...I'll follow up with more detail in a bit, I just didn't want to over complicate things.

Comment: I found some documentation that mentions if a child process adds items to a queue but doesn't use JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread then it could cause a process to hang on exit when it tries to join. I guess I don't see why that would only be the case when spawning 5+ processes vs. 4 or less.